# Could client side javascript act as a web spider?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

Could ajax be used on the client side javascript to function as an in-the-background web spider? You'll have to excuse the vagueness of this post because I really have no idea where to begin technically in terms of the code and there is nothing online about a program like this.

Comment: No.Because of cross domain restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible but with some restrictions, meant only to be done from a specially-configured browser, not for arbitrary users to just run:
For chrome, open it using the command-line parameter --disable-web-security.
now you can do cross domain and such.

I assume you just want it for using yourself as a server and not on a public web page.

Comment: could I make ajax requests to different hosts if I used the command-line parameter --disable-web-security

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cors proxy type script in order to do these Ajax requests client side via javascript. Look on Github for 'cors proxy', and set that up in your Node.js environment, then pass all of your ajax calls client side through this proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make ajax requests to different hosts, so no.

Comment: could you do it without ajax?

Comment: You can't "load" pages with javascript without ajax whitout actually navigating to that page. Once you navigate to another page your javascript does not run anymore. 
Short answer this is not possible at all.